# What happen if I forgot to add Core Data when creates the project in xcode 7+ ,ios 9,with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios9, xcode7

I have an ios project written in objective C. When I create the project I forgot to add core data (absolutely at that moment I create the project, I didn't have a need of core data and now I want). so is it a matter with Xcodee 7+ and if I add now core data to my project, can I continue with the normal way. Or else do I have to copy & paste files from a project which created with core data. Searching for a better and easy way to do this.

how can I do this.hope your helpful answer with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select the use `CoreData` option in the new project wizard, it just puts in some boilerplate code and includes the `CoreData` framework in your build settings.  You can do this after the fact with no problems.

There are plenty of tutorials that will show you how to do this as well.  They are easy to find with a cursory google search.

If you don't want to go through the trouble of finding a tutorial, the easiest thing to do is create a new project with CoreData and add the pieces in that project that are missing in yours (last time I looked at the template project, most of the CoreData code was in the app delegate, and of course you'll need to add a data model file).

UPDATE: Removed link to first tutorial I found doing a cursory google search, since it is no longer available.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: This is why we don't include links in our answer without explaining the content.

Comment: @bkribbs The point of that statement was to indicate that there are _many_ examples that are easily found with Google.  Not to endorse a particular one.